# Laravel whereRaw using date

Tags: php, laravel

I have variable called `$date`

when I used `dd();` it will return something like this

[image]

`"2022-02-15"`

But when I try to use the variable `$date` in my where statement it's not working.

My query looks like this

**Ex#1**

```
      $data = Order::whereNull('deleted_at')
                    ->where( 'status_level' , 1)
                    ->where('overall_status', 'Not Yet Validated')
                    ->whereRaw("date(created_at) = '".$date."'");
```

The query is not working.

[image]

But when I tried to use something like this

**Ex#2**

```
      $data = Order::whereNull('deleted_at')
                    ->where( 'status_level' , 1)
                    ->where('overall_status', 'Not Yet Validated')
                    ->whereRaw("date(created_at) = '2022-02-15'");
```

I am getting the right output, should I say it's working.

[image]

Comment: chain `->toSql()` at the end to get what query is built at the end

Answer (score 0):

Add `get()`or `first()` behind your query. Like

```
  $data = Order::whereNull('deleted_at')
                    ->where( 'status_level' , 1)
                    ->where('overall_status', 'Not Yet Validated')
                    ->whereRaw("date(created_at) = '2022-02-15'")->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `whereDate`

```
$data = Order::whereNull('deleted_at')
          ->where( 'status_level' , 1)
          ->where('overall_status', 'Not Yet Validated')
          ->whereDate('created_at', $date )->get();
```